# Is it against the law (Federal, Provincial or Civil), in Regina, Saskatchewan, to NOT allow customers to use a toilet in a major grocery store?

Tags: canada, business, health, civil-legal-system

Yesterday, while doing my (quite large) grocery shopping, I “felt the need” to use the bathroom.  I went to where the bathroom was, and the sign was gone, and the door was locked! I asked a worker if they had moved it or what?!? She informed me that they no longer offered bathroom facilities to customers!  I was sure they are doing so outside the rules of the law, but all I can find in looking for it, is restaurants and workers rights!  Surely there is someone, somehow, who can answer my question!  Signed- A cross-legged-grocery-leave-the-cart-right-there kinda girl!

Answer (score 2):

### There is no general requirement to provide toilets for customers

Restaurants are required to provide them under the [Public Eating Establishment Standards](https://teachers.plea.org/newsletter/2018/the-plea-the-bathroom-barrister/32.2-3). There is a requirement under the Occupational Health and Safety Regulations, 2020 to provide them for workers.

But for grocery stores or other businesses: no.